# Go to n-th character in text string using RPG and DSPF

Tags: rpgle

I have a program that runs an interactive DSPF. Now I'm populating a field with characters in the RPG program. The first two characters 'ab'. However what I want is that when I'm going through my DSPF when I tab to that field, the cursor is placed under the 'a' because that's the first position of the field. I want to jump to the 3rd position of the field so my cursor is after my input so I can easily continue my input rather than hit the arrow key. Just wondering if there is a way to do this. I already know about DSPATR(PC) however that makes sure it goes to the first position where I want the 3rd position. CURLOC is record level which doesn't help me, I just want this one text string to be positioned at the 3rd character instead of first once tabbed to it. I want to have the option to change those first 2 characters as well, that's why I haven't simply made them a variable and concatenated them or just incorporate behind the scenes. I just want to tab to a text string and the cursor be in the 3rd character position.

Comment: IF you want to position always at 3° char, why don't you create 2 fields, the first with 2 char and the second ... and you set Position Cursor on second field

Comment: Because then I have to concatenate them back together because all the information has to be sent once submitted. It changes a lot of other code as well. I thought about doing this. But I really just want to tab to the 3rd character.

Comment: Then you can use two fields (2 Chars + X Chars) into the DSPF, and use position cursor on the 1° char of X CHARS Field. In the rpg you read and write fields through a DS.

Comment: Again this would add more code because there is also an F4 prompt that brings up a menu with a list of entries in it, if you select one it populates the whole field in the entire string on the line. If I have two fields this code would need to be changed as well. That's why I said, when I start changing the field it multiplies the code changes needed. I really just want the tab to go to the third position. It's odd this really hasn't been addressed more or coded to account for individual fields to do this.

Comment: I feel like CSRLOC might work, however I'm having an indicator define problem. However I think it's going to default to that field at the opening of the page, not simply when you tab down to that field, which is truly what I want. Seems like the coders should have considered this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `CSRLOC` is your answer..
from the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakc/rzakcmstdfcsrlc.htm)

> The format of the keyword is:
>
> CSRLOC(field-name-1 field-name-2)
>
> The parameter values on the
>   keyword specify the names of two fields whose contents are the line
>   number (for field-name-1) and the position number (for field-name-2)
>   of the cursor location. Field-name-1 and field-name-2 are 3-byte,
>   zoned decimal, hidden fields. Your program uses these fields to tell
>   the IBM® i operating system where to locate the cursor.

```
A          R RECORD1                   CSRLOC(LINNBR POSNBR)
A            TITLE         40   B  1  2
A            PAGE           5Y OB  1 60
A            TEXT        1760   B  2  1
A            LINNBR         3  OH
A            POSNBR         3  OH
```

The fact that it's record level doesn't matter as I/O is done via a record, not a field.  When the record is `EXFMT` the cursor will be positioned where you've requested.

If that doesn't work, your only other possible option would be to get rid of the display file and use the [Dynamic Screen Manager (DSM) APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/apis/dsm.htm) to interface with the screen directly.

Comment: Well it looks like it's a subfile and I thought I read that CSRLOC doesn't work with subfiles.

Comment: Nevermind. It's not a subfile. I thought it was because there are so many layers to this dspf. However it's not a subfile. I'm getting an error with compile saying that the indicator isn't defined. Which doesn't make a lot of sense because I'm defining it right here in the dspf. :/